# Find the number to which the difference of two finite sequences approaches

Tags: sequences-and-series

For example, I have two sequences of real numbers: $$S_{10}={\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}\}$$ and $$A_{10}=\{{2.1,3.4, 5.6, 1.2, 3.6, 4.5, 2.3, 3.5, 5.3, 6.7}\}$$

I want to find out how close the difference of these two sequences is, to the number $0$, i.e.,

$$B_{10} = S_{10} - A_{10}$$

The solution I came up, was to take the difference of finite sequence $B_{10}$ (I'll call it$\space D_{10}$), $$D_{10} = diff(B_{10})$$ and impose conditions on this new sequence $D_{10}$:

1. Let $N$ be the number of items in the sequence, then $\forall n<=N, d_{n-1}>d_{n}$
2. given condition $1$ is true, let $\sigma$ be an arbitrary number which is sufficiently small (e.g., 0.0000001), if the distance between the last number in the sequence $D_{10}$ and zero, is smaller than $\sigma$, I'll say this sequence is sufficiently close to the number 0,
   $$|d_{N} - 0| <= \sigma $$

Is this solution correct? Is there a more robust solution to this problem?

Comment: Don't repost questions. This question is still about finite sequences, and thus questions of convergence don't make sense.

Comment: I see you have mostly rewritten the question, but the word "approaches" in the title still implies convergence. Please rephrase the title to reflect the actual question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I’ve rewritten the question, entirely, especially after the lengthy discussion we had just now, about what is series, sequence and convergence. Therefore this question deserves a repost as it is a different question than the one I asked before, which wasn’t clear. This is my actual question. And I couldn’t find a better word instead of “approach”, as I said am not from math major, can you suggest one? Or a different title?

Comment: And to be utterly clear, I reposted it out of respect to what you’ve commented before, which led me to clarify the relevant concepts myself and help me clear the cloud in my head to write a better question such that for people that have very good mathematics knowledge, like you, can understand and leave as little room for confusion as possible. However, I am still learning and this site is also for learners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old but interesting problem. Computer scientists use this notion to compare partially computed numbers. Geneticists use it to compare DNA as mutations can shorten, lengthen, or simply change a term.
A good solution is to usually to step away from regular metrics and use partial metrics.

You would need to tweek the partial metric to what end result you are looking for. [This](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Samer-Assaf-2/publication/265052270_Partial_metric_spaces_with_negative_distances_and_fixed_point_theorems/links/564b558808ae3374e5dd9273/Partial-metric-spaces-with-negative-distances-and-fixed-point-theorems.pdf) is a paper I wrote a while ago that discusses an example in DNA and introduces you to partial metrics.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks very much for introducing me to partial metrics :) I’ll give it a read and revert back for anything I don’t understand.

Comment: You're welcome. If it looks too complicated, I have a much bigger document, in fact my thesis that introduces you much more slowly but takes more time [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/301848131_Generalized_Metrics). And yes, you are more than welcome to ask me any questions you need. Glad to help.

Comment: :) I tend to dwell on things, learning it slowly is just perfect; I like big document that has rich information on the subject hehe, thanks Sam!